# Room MigrationTestHelper is deprecated

Tags: android, android-room, android-testing

I want to write a JUnit test for my database migrations like as android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions#all-migrations-test) says, but in room version 2.4.1 MigrationTestHelper is deprecated, is there any alternative for this to test my legacy code that used manual migration?

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MigrationTest {
    private val TEST_DB = "migration-test"

    // Array of all migrations
    private val ALL_MIGRATIONS = arrayOf(
        PersistenceModule.MIGRATION_7_8,
        PersistenceModule.MIGRATION_8_9,
        PersistenceModule.MIGRATION_9_10,
        PersistenceModule.MIGRATION_10_11,
        PersistenceModule.MIGRATION_11_12,
        PersistenceModule.MIGRATION_12_13,
        PersistenceModule.MIGRATION_13_14
    )

    @get:Rule
    val helper: MigrationTestHelper = MigrationTestHelper(
        InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation(),
        AppDatabase::class.java.canonicalName,
        FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelperFactory()
    )

    @Test
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun migrateAll() {
       
        helper.createDatabase(TEST_DB, 7).apply {
            close()
        }

        Room.databaseBuilder(
            InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext,
            AppDatabase::class.java,
            TEST_DB
        ).addMigrations(*ALL_MIGRATIONS).build().apply {
            openHelper.writableDatabase.close()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's simply not true; only 2 of the 5 constructors had been deprecated:

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/testing/MigrationTestHelper

Most likely because:

> Cannot be used to run migration tests involving `AutoMigration`.

Comment: thank you, with passing the specs argument to the constructor it was solved!